# Bridge Information

Tags: discussion

A first time poster just posted IPs and fingerprints of a few bridges.
https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/4920/350

Is it OK to do this?

It is my understanding (or fantasy?) that it is not, that bridges should not be publicly known as such, and that people who need bridges should contact Tor Project to obtain some.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. Bridge addresses should not be shared publicly, lest they risk becoming blacklisted by censoring ISPs and governments.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. I've edited the answer, but by this point the damage is probably done.

I'll try to keep an eye out for these in future. The community can also help police these and suggest edits when caught in the wild.